# Terminate single instance of process

Tags: process, instance, terminate

Not sure if this is possible but here it goes. I have a simple server set up where multiple clients could execute a program. Each time a client executes the script to start the program, a new instance of the program starts. Now when the client stops the program execution thru another script, the instance of the program is killed. The problem is if another client is on the server at the same time running the program that instance will be killed also. Is there any way to connect a particular instance to a particular client?

Here is more detail.
The server is used to stream media from the internet. I have streaming devices attached to tvs. When a particular channel is selected, it sends a signal to the server which in turn runs several scripts, one being a script to start a video conversion process thru program called ffmpeg. The ffmpeg coverts the stream, saves it to a folder on the server making it available to the streaming device/tv. Each time a user starts a channel, an instance of the ffmpeg starts because its converting a different stream. Once the user ends viewing, the device sends a signal back to the server thru php script, which in turn runs a script called cleanup. The cleanup script is a bat file that kills the ffmpeg and deletes the files that are no longer needed. All works great except if one individual elects to stop viewing while the other continues. I don't know how to tell the difference between each instance of ffmpeg. I don't want it to kill all instances just the one connected to the one particular stream that needs to end. I do have the capability of obtaining each device ip address when the user first selects the channel. Is there anyway to link the ip to the particular instance?

Comment: I think you are going to need to show us the code... can the server detect its client has closed? If so, it could kill itself. Can the client tell the server it is closing? If so, the server could kill itself. http://stefan.buettcher.org/cs/conn_closed.html

Comment: Here's an off-the-wall idea... maybe you could copy "ffmpeg.exe" to a new name before running it then there is a differently named "ffmpeg" for each client. So, say client's IP address is 192.168.0.34, rename "ffmpeg.exe" to "ffmpeg.192.168.0.34.exe" before running it, then you know which instance to kill :-)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I might try that but I think I maybe able to use netstat and manipulate some the info since each new instance uses a different PID. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually took advice from above and renamed each instance as ip, stored ip in temp file, was then able to match it to the ip making the cancel call.